# Characters change from danish

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, character-encoding

In a SSIS-package i load alot of columns from one stagetable in a source system into another table in the Data Warehouse.
2 columns can contain the danish letters. 
Name - varchar(200)
Address1 - varchar(100)
They both have code page 1252.
Name haas æøå changed to other chars but address1 works fine.
If i put a data viewer on the line exiting the Sourcecomponent it will show the changes already there. In preview on the sourcecomponent everything looks fine.
How do i fix this?

I have tried making a new package from ground.

I need the danish letters ÆØÅ in the outgoing result

Comment: Since it is a staging table, try changing the column's data type to nvarchar

Comment: Actually i did just try that and it worked. But i prefer the stagetable to be a 100% copy of the sourcetable. And it works fine for all other varchar-columns in the table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to cast the NAME column as nvarchar and then make a transformationtask that changed it back to varchar. That worked for some reason. But still not the solution i was hoping for.